# moment.js is changing the time of input to the timezoone whereas it's meant to already be that timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timezone, momentjs

So im trying to use moment.js to do some time converting, im using Angular to do some data binding with this just for clarity

```
$scope.resolveTime = function () {

    var m = moment.tz($scope.inputTime, 'America/Los_Angeles');
    $scope.inputTime = m;
    var zone = jstz.determine();

    $scope.outputTime = m.tz(zone.name()); // Convert CDT to local time

    console.log("inputtime:  " + $scope.inputTime.format())
    console.log("local:  " + $scope.outputTime.format())
};
```

I thought it would be simple enough but what im guess is happening is that when I pass the inputTime and tell moment it's `America/Los_Angeles` it then converts the current local time to PDT rather than set it to PDT, becasue then the code below converts it back to the local timezone resulting in the exact same numbers for both variables. Anyone know a way to get around this?
The result should be that the user inputs a time (in PDT) and it will show what time that is in the users local time.

Update: after looking into this more I think it's actually my time picker changing the input into a Date object which is then local, the time picker i am using is Angular Ui Boostrap for reference

Comment: If the `$scope.inputTime` already has a timezone offset in it, moment will use it first and then convert to the timezone you specified. Add some logging before and after each step so you can see exactly how the value is being modified.

Comment: That makes sense thanks, however I just tried initializing `$scope.inputTime =  moment.tz( 'America/Los_Angeles');` and when I log it im still getting my local time, however I just noticed that it's comming up in a Date format not moment. I have a feeling that it might be Angular reformatting it

Comment: On futher inspection I think it might actually be my time picker doing it. Im using the Angular UI Boostrap time picker, looks like i'll have to reroll my own

Comment: This might help. It adds a custom directive that fixes the date. https://gist.github.com/weberste/354a3f0a9ea58e0ea0de

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made a little easier.

First of all, Moments are mutable. This is why `$scope.inputTime` and `$scope.outputTime` have the same value. You can fix this using `.clone()` to clone the Moment.

Also, to get the date into the user's local time, you can just rely on behavior built into the browser, and moment's `.local()` function. There is no need to go to jstz for the user's local time unless you really want to know their time zone.

It is worth noting that Moment Timezone built in the functionality that jstz provides as of 0.5.0 (December 2015) with `moment.tz.guess()`.

Putting it all together, your code should look something like this:

```
function () {

var m = moment.tz($scope.inputTime, 'America/Los_Angeles');
$scope.inputTime = m;

$scope.outputTime = m.clone().local(); // Convert CDT to local time

console.log("inputtime:  " + $scope.inputTime.format())
console.log("local:  " + $scope.outputTime.format())
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that clarification, I do like including less js libraries if I can this will do it for me though, just needa fix up my time picker and she's good to go

Comment: If you are attached to your date picker, then you are attached to it. If you happen to already be using jquery/moment/boostrap in your project, you could look at the Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker. That uses a moment instead of a date for everything. I believe it supports moments in a timezone as of last September. This would make your code a lot easier.